# Selenium, after open Chrome signed with my account, the python script doesn't seem getting executed

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm running a simple script which accesses to a page and clicks on a button, but looks like Selenium loses the focus or kind of.
This is happening after I set the option to open the browser (Chrome) being signed with my account (since I need one extension to be available, and logged in)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.headless = False  # Set to True if you don't want to see the browser window
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome")

#provide location where chrome stores profiles

# Initialize the browser
chrome_driver_path = '/Users/myusername/Documents/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)

# Navigate to the URL
url = "https://www.somewhere.com"
driver.get(url)

def getElAfterRendered(el):
  return WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(el)

def css(selector):
  return EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))

def xpath(selector):
  return EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, selector))

css_sel_swap_link = getElAfterRendered(css('#subtitle a'))
css_sel_swap_link.click()
```

Comment: Since you are trying to click on that element, try and check with "element_to_be_clickable".

Comment: I've just realised that Selenium can't manage two instance of Chrome if you open it with your profile